# tableViewCell image property reset when selected - swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I do create a custom cell with 2 `UIImageView` inside and a `UILabel` this way:

```
        let ChildCellID = "ChildCell"
        if indexPath.section < 2 {
            var cell = SectionCell.loadOrDequeueWithTableView(tableView, reuseIdentifier: SectionCellID)

            if cell == nil {
                cell = SectionCell.viewFromNib()
            }
            cell.delegate = self as SectionCellDelegate
            cell.avatar?.loadAvatarURL(child.avatarUrl)
            cell.avatar.layer.cornerRadius = cell.avatar.frame.size.width / 2
```

The attribut avatar is the `UIImageView` I decided to round. When a cell is selected my code goes:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {
    let tableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    if let cell : SectionCell = tableViewCell as? SectionCell {
        cell.selection = !cell.selection

    } else if let cell : ChildCell = tableViewCell as? ChildCell {
        cell.selection = !cell.selection
    }
    return indexPath
}
```

Selection is the checkbox as `UIImageView`. My problem is when I select a cell, the cell.avatar loses his property meaning it goes back as a square form. The cell.avatar is still loaded and I tried `cell.avatar.layer.cornerRadius = cell.avatar.frame.size.width / 2`in the `willSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` but without success.

Am I missing anything that makes my avatar loses his rounded property ?
The only thing that could possibly be the origin of this problem would be the fact that I do use the checkbox `UIImageView` which is really near my avatar.

Comment: cell.avatar.layer.cornerRadius = cell.avatar.frame.size.width / 2
cell.avatar.ClipToBounds = true
Try this in your cell for row

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the checkbox near my avatar lacked a constraints that, for some random reason and even though it did not impact the avatar view, was resetting the avatar view rounded property.